# Powershell For Loop to add a semicolon after each value

Tags: powershell, string, loop

I want to loop through a collection of items and append semicolon after each item.

Example Output values from `mycollection`: 
5590
6063
1213

Expected Output: 
5590;6063;1213

Below is my code.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $myCollection.Count; $i++) 
{
$cmID =  $cmID + $myCollection[$i].Label + ";"
}
$cmID.Substring(0,$cmsID.Length-1) #This is to remove the last semicolon
```

Using above code, I am getting output as:

```
55905590;6063;1213
```

But I want the output as: `5590;6063;1213`

Comment: just add $cmID ="" before the for loop and it should be fine.

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is not related to SharePoint so should be on Stack Exchange.

PowerShell does not need to be verbose. You can do what you need very simply:

```
$myCollection -join ";"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$myCollection = "Apple","Pear","Banana","Orange"
$cmID = ""
foreach($item in $myCollection)
{
    $cmID += $item + ";"
}
Write-Host $cmID
```